# How do i find the length of array[N][M]?

Tags: c

how to i find the length of each word that user type. Example word hi has length 2

```
#define N 99
#define M 99
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int a,i,count=0;
char x[N][M];

for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
printf("input word,\n input ****end for exit: ");
scanf("%s", x[i]);
a=strcmp(x[i], "****end");
if(a==0) break;
count++;
}
for(i=0;i<count;i++){
printf("%s", x[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the "How to Ask page" for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I dont know why it is so hard to understand this simple question. i am asking how to find the length of 2D array[i]

Comment: @user3577378, it is difficult to understand because there is no such thing as the length of a 2D array. There is the size of an array, its number of elements, or the length of a *string*, that is the position of the first 0 character. So what are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `strlen(x[i])` with `printf` using `%zu` for type `size_t`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 99
#define M 99

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a,i,count=0;
    char x[N][M];


    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
        printf("input word,\n input ****end for exit: ");
        scanf("%s", x[i]);
        a=strcmp(x[i], "****end");
        if(a==0) break;
        count++;
    }
    for (i=0;i<count;i++){
        printf("%s\t", x[i]);
        printf("%zu\n", strlen(x[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3577378, It is the format specifier for the type `size_t` which is the return value for `strlen`.

Comment: REPLACED %zu with %d AND WORKED!

Comment: @user3577378: No, replacing `"%zu"` with `"%d"` does not work ... you merely got **UNLUCKY**. If you want to use `"%d"` (because you do not have a C99 compiler), you need to cast the value: `printf("%d\n", (int)strlen(x[i]));`